# Working with Excel 2007 from win32 application

Tags: c++, excel, com, excel-2007

Can you tell me Where I can see a examples (sources of simple application on c++ (for Visual Studio)) a working with excel 2007 and 2003 from win32 application. Especially with Chart object. Thanks!

Comment: There are a few notes on Stackoverflow that may be of interest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b%20excel

Comment: I see this, but i don't find any examples of working with Excel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One you created COM object of Excel.Application, you can call the same methods this object have in VBScript.

Use some wizard of your IDE to make a wrapper for this ActiveX or use this awkward method:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/216686